# Highcharts zoom is triggering 'style="display: block !important"' on hidden graphs on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, safari

So I have a set of synchronized graphs similar to the Highcharts demo 'Synchronized graphs'. I have some buttons that let you hide and show only specific graphs. However, when zooming, all the graphs that are hidden (with display: none) suddenly are updated to style="display: block !important".

I've noticed that this issue only occurs on Safari. It works perfect on both Chrome and Firefox.

Here's a jsfiddle that replicates this issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/huangj/49wg0pnL/

```
  $('#button1').on('click', function(){
    console.log('1 clicked');
  $('#0').toggle();
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be a kind of issue with jQuery toggle - when I set css directly it works correctly. See example https://jsfiddle.net/t618sqhk/

Comment: Are you using safari? I just tested your fiddle in Safari and it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Yes, Safari 10.1.1 on mcOS Sierra 10. What is your OS and browser versions?

Comment: Ah so this is running safari 8 on OS X Yosemite. I'll update and see if that works. Thanks!